# Any jQuery plugin something like google+ image collage

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

One way is to use these two plugins to create google+ style photo display http://www.sohtanaka.com/web-design/fancy-thumbnail-hover-effect-w-jquery/ and there are tons of other slider plugins available.By merging two we can do the respective work. But i dont want to reinvent the wheel.

Is there any plugin already available..??

Comment: WHich two plugins are you referring to? Do you have a screenshot/demo URL of the end result? I don't have access to google+

Comment: @Mrchief  mail me ur email id @ jain.mohit27@gmail.com will send u.

Comment: My email address is in my profile :)

Comment: @Mrchief, I sent you an invitation to Google+

Comment: Reinventing the wheel makes sometimes the wheel a bit rounder! :)

Comment: @roXon: where did ou find that? lol :)

Comment: :) I had to invent it. For the *wheel* thing is (ab)used too often this days and it hurts my *creative* feelings

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[jQuery/CSS3 photo gallery tutorials](http://blog.templatemonster.com/2011/04/14/jquery-css3-photo-gallery-tutorials-html5-website/)

Answer (score 5):

This one seems to combine fancybox plugin with CSS gallery: http://tutorialzine.com/2009/11/hovering-gallery-css3-jquery/.

Also, this one also seems good: http://pikachoose.com/how-to-fancybox/

Few more:
http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettyphoto-jquery-lightbox-clone/
http://minishowcase.net/
http://visuallightbox.com/index.html
http://www.pirolab.it/pirobox/

There are lot in [here](http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/css/57-free-image-gallery-slideshow-and-lightbox-solutions/), I suggested few that fit close to what you're looking for.

Comment: dude i have specified these plugins in my question.. That merging two can solve my problem. I was just looking for something which is already done, by some1. anyways thats for your links..

Answer (score 2):

I know this is late. But there is a plugin which displays a list of images directly as a collage with drag drop etc.

https://github.com/sandeepravi/collage

Answer (score 1):

Bit late to answer this one but here is a simple plugin that creates a google+ style photo display and will retrieve images from a google+ album.

Get the code from github: https://github.com/dantium/jQuery-Plus-Pics

View a demo here: http://www.danatkinson.com/demo/googlepluspics/

Answer (score 0):

I also need to create collage with jquery and read this question and other too. After analysis,

I found the perfect solution via CSS link from below link and I am extend the collage functionality with search image option:

[How do I dynamically create a collage (grid with no gaps) of images, where images have different heights?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6541078/how-do-i-dynamically-create-a-collage-grid-with-no-gaps-of-images-where-image)

Css collage link : https://css-tricks.com/seamless-responsive-photo-grid/